# IOS8 NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios8

My app used to work on ios5 to ios7. Recently I tried to run on ios8 with xcode6 and simulator8. The app crashed. I found the exception "NSInvalidArgumentException, reason - [UILabel selectedSegmentIndex] unrecognized selector sent to instance" When it reached [[self weightUnitsc_s] setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5765 blue:0.4431 alpha:1];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (indexPath.section==0){
    if (indexPath.row==0){
        weight * cell=(weight *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"weightcell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSLog(@"weight nil");
            NSArray* arr=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"weight" owner:self options:nil];
            cell= [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            [[cell weightUnitsc] setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.weightUnitsc.frame.origin.x, cell.weightUnitsc.frame.origin.y+5, cell.weightUnitsc.frame.size.width, 30)];
            [[cell weightUnitsc] addTarget:self action:@selector(segChange2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        }
        [cell LabelText:[Language get:@"setting.weightUnit" alter:@""]];
        [cell SegText:[Language get:@"setting.weightUnit.kg" alter:@""] :0];
        [cell SegText:[Language get:@"setting.weightUnit.g" alter:@""] :1];
        [cell SegText:[Language get:@"setting.weightUnit.lbs" alter:@""] :2];
        [cell SegText:[Language get:@"setting.weightUnit.oz" alter:@""] :3];


        [self setWeightUnitsc_s:[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:1]];
        switch ([WeightUnit getCurrentWeightID]) {
            case 1:
                [[self weightUnitsc_s] setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
                break;
            case 2:
                [[self weightUnitsc_s] setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];
                break;
            case 3:
                [[self weightUnitsc_s] setSelectedSegmentIndex:3];
                break;
            default:
                [[self weightUnitsc_s] setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
                break;
        }
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [cell setBackgroundView:[[[UACellBackgroundView alloc] init] autorelease]];
        [(UACellBackgroundView *)[cell backgroundView] setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionTop];

        return cell;
    }
```

can someone please help to explain and fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your code assumes that `[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:1]` is a `UISegmentedControl` when in fact it is a `UILabel`.

Comment: This is what happens when you rely on subview index rather than accessing actual objects themselves. When Apple makes changes to the view hierarchy in any way, your code is stuffed. Add a property that points to the segmented control you want in your `weight` cell (terrible name by the way), and then access your segmented control via that property

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think I know how to fix it.